# Accessing swagger-ui.html in an application using Thymeleaf as view technology

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, swagger-ui

I am developing a web app in java using **thymeleaf - templating**, **spring security**, **swagger for api documentation of the rest endpoints** in the application. Everything is working fine with exception of the fact that am unable to access the **swagger-ui.html** page

I have already added filters to ignore the swagger endpoints in spring security. I am able to access the `v2/api-docs` link as json in the browser. However, I am getting the error below when i access `swagger-ui.html`

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jan 02 13:32:46 EAT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "swagger-ui", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Comment: can you post your swagger configuration?

Comment: `@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
 
 @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.dst.frontend.api"))              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();
    }
}`